# What does a question mark inside parentheses (?) mean?

Tags: meaning, question-mark

If a sentence/word has (?) at the end, does it mean the sentence is not a fact and the author is not sure about it?
As in the example:

I am the tallest(?) in our class.

Which means I am not sure whether I am tallest in the class.

Is it correct?

Comment: It's very informal writing.

Comment: It can also mean you are unsure about the spelling/word.

Comment: Somewhat close to `[citation needed]` :)

Answer (score 18):

(?) is simply a passing note of incertitude at the preceding word (sometimes phrase).

> I am the tallest(?) in our class

Here this usage indicates that the author is not sure if he/she is really the tallest one.

Comment: It might also mean that the author isn't sure whether it is the right word.

Comment: @Lebbers I think that is also covered by `incertitude at the preceding word`.

Comment: Similar to `(sp?)`, which means the author isn't sure if the spelling of the last word or phrase is correct. E.g. "I met a guy named Asrael (sp?) ..."

Comment: @wjandrea In my experience, it refers to uncertainty of truthiness far more often than uncertainty of spelling

Comment: @person27 What do you mean?

Comment: (?) is only similar to (sp?) in the context of proofreading, but your statement implies that's its primary purpose. I noted that I usually see it outside of proofreading to mean the author is unsure of something.

Comment: @person27 I'm saying `(sp?)` is used to indicate the author is unsure of spelling. I'm still not sure what you mean. BTW, do you mean "truthfulness" instead of "truthiness"?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen the use of "(?)" in any book or news article for example, I would say it's something used in an informal context. But yes, I'd say it showcases the author's insecurity with respect to the statement

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is more of a comment than an answer. You can quite quickly earn the ability to comment with a few votes on a good question or a good answer. Perhaps take a look at [how to answer](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer/).

Comment: @tmgr On all other stackexchange sites, comments are for asking for clarification. Here, too, the placeholder says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements". A comment is not supposed to be an answer. Caproki, I think you were right in posting your answer as, y'know, an answer.